# Control a button inside a MovieClip in the Main timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, action

I've been searching for a solution to my problem for hours now but I can't find one. My problem is that I have some buttons inside a MovieClip and I want to control them from the Main timeline. But here's the weird part. The button I have in the first frame in the MovieClip works just fine, but the other two buttons, which is in frame 2 and 3, wont work when I click on them and I get this error message because of the buttons:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Eksamen_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Thank you!

Comment: What do the buttons do? Can you give some code?

Comment: The buttons job is to push a value into an array, summing up values in an another array I've made, and also go to the next frame and previous frame. Here is the code: `mc.btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn1Action); function btn1Action (evt:MouseEvent) { regUt.push(mc.txt1.text); point.push(int(mc.txt2.text) + int(mc.txt3.text) + int(mc.txt3.text)); mc.nextFrame(); } mc.btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn2Action); function btn2Action(evt:MouseEvent) { mc.prevFrame(); }` The code is outside the MovieClip and in the Main timeline in frame 1. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Well it doesn't matter what the buttons do, because even there's nothing in the button's function, I will still get the error message I typed above :/

Comment: I think I see the issue now. You're trying to access buttons that are on other frames than the first, but from the main timeline. I don't have much experience with coding on the timeline, but I don't think this is possible. This page seems to talk about a similar issue, maybe it'll help: http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?825278-accessibilty-of-instances-in-different-frames

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now I finally understand whats the problem! :D

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your problem might be on your timeline. Try to place each button on a single keyframe. Then use yourMovieClip.visible = true or false to hide/show your movieclips on different frames.